# What to cast a Process class (sender) thread to....in event handler

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

For instance, a thread that is a BackgroundWorker, can be cast like:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker senderWorker
                = sender as System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker;
    }
```

The code above represents what I have for my Background worker thread. I cast [sender] as a BackGround Worker - because I know thats what he is.

I can't seem to find what I should cast it to if: instead of a Background worker, what if I had used a Process class, and executed say a DOS batch file, using:

```
enter code here
```

Process proc = new Process();
proc.FileName = "some_dos_batch_file.bat";
proc.Exited = ProcessExited; 
proc.Start();

Sorry about syntax, but when this process completes, its completion will be handled by 'ProcessExited' below. But What should I cast the sender arg to in THAT case - NOT a Background Worker obviously, but I'm not sure to what? I would like to use the .Results property the same as I did for the Background worker.

Thanks - sorry for the confusion.

```
enter code here




    void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
     }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more as it does not make sense in relation to 'process that was told to start and is now exited'? Please do include code as we're not psychic debuggers/mindreaders for us SO'ers to be able to help you....

Comment: I added some more info. Thanks. YOu know you are of limited use to me if you can't mind read! just kidding. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your question, if not, please clarify. If you are talking about threading and using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` then you would need to use Thread events...consider this below a simple class called `TestARP` that shells out to the command line using a hidden window to retrieve the MAC/IP address of the active connection, with the output of the command redirected to a stream which is appended to a stringbuilder instance:

```
public class TestARP
{
    private StringBuilder sbRedirectedOutput = new StringBuilder();
    public string OutputData
    {
        get { return this.sbRedirectedOutput.ToString(); }
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ps = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        ps.FileName = "arp";
        ps.ErrorDialog = false;
        ps.Arguments = "-a";
        ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ps.UseShellExecute = false;
        ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ps.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = ps;
            proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
            proc.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            while (!proc.HasExited) ;
        }
    }

    void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("proc_Exited: Process Ended");
    }

    void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null) this.sbRedirectedOutput.Append(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("proc_OutputDataReceived: Data: " + e.Data);
    }
}
```

If you were to run this in a thread the Process's events will still get caught (***only on the thread itself***), but if you're talking about waiting for the thread to finish, look at this class code here called `ThreadTestARP` that runs the above class on a thread...

```
public class ThreadTestARP
{
    private TestARP _testARP = new TestARP();
    private ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public ThreadTestARP()
    {
    }
    public TestARP ARPTest
    {
        get { return this._testARP; }
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunThread));
        t.Start();
        this._mre.WaitOne();
        // Blocks here...
        t.Join();
    }
    private void RunThread()
    {
        this._testARP.Run();
        this._mre.Set();
    }
}
```

Note how the ManualResetEvent `_mre` is used to signal to say in the context of the thread, "right, I am done, back to the creator..."

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you cast to a Process object?  You can still access some members of Process objects, such as ExitCode or ExitTime, that have terminated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx